# Arduino ADK + Android LED blink example compiling errors

Tags: arduino, android

I'm trying to make a project using the [Arduino ADK board](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK)  and a Sony Ericsson Xperia Play running *Android 2.3.4*. For starters all I want to do is blink a LED from my Android device, using the [nice tutorial found here](http://allaboutee.com/2011/12/31/arduino-adk-board-blink-an-led-with-your-phone-code-and-explanation/). I managed to compile the Android app but I'm having big difficulties on the Arduino sketch. I can't resolve the imports and it won't compile. I understant there are some Arduino IDE version issues. I tried compiling on both 0023 and on 1.0. The furthest I could go with the code was getting these compile errors:

```
D:\arduino-0023\libraries\AndroidAccessory/AndroidAccessory.h:37: error: 'EP_RECORD' does not name a type
D:\arduino-0023\libraries\AndroidAccessory/AndroidAccessory.h:50: error: 'EP_RECORD' has not been declared
D:\arduino-0023\libraries\AndroidAccessory/AndroidAccessory.h:50: error: 'EP_RECORD' has not been declared
D:\arduino-0023\libraries\AndroidAccessory/AndroidAccessory.h:64: error: 'USB_NAK_LIMIT' was not declared in this scope
```

I think I read the whole documentation and I can't find a solution to my problem. Setting this up is such a pain... I really need to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

The library was written and tested in:

Arduino Alpha 0022

Have you tried this?

```
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
  #include "Arduino.h"
#else
  #include "WProgram.h" #endif
```

Comment: yes I did :( this small header edit got me this far but still left me with the errors you see above...